# Discussion List showing wrong thread

Tags: list-view, xslt-list-view-web-part, discussion-board

I have a relatively large discussion list (~2000 discussions with ~8000 replies). Clicking through on any discussion in the discussion list does not take me to the correct thread, rather it surfaces the same list item for any discussion that is clicked. Switching the view from the default `Subject` view to another view, I am able to view the correct threads. Has anyone ever experienced this? If so, do you know why this occurs and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this and unfortunately this is OOTB behaviour for views that are not "Subject". For example, if you view the "Management" view, you'll see the same thing.

I resolved it by overwriting the "onclick" function and redirecting it to the correct page. Each link has an onclick event which calls "EnterFolder". I used JavaScript to override this function:

$(document).ready(function(){
    window.EnterFolder = function(url){
        url = "http://newurl.com";  //assign the URL of the detail page flat.aspx
        window.location.href = url;
    };
});

Be warned that I'm overriding a MS JavaScript function. I don't know what else it does.

I hope this helps.

Brian